# Find the area bounded by $g(x)$ and $x$ axis from $x =-2 $ to $x=6$ where $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)=x^3 +3x+2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the area bounded by $g(x)$ and $x$ axis between $x=-2$ to $x=6 $.  $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)= x^3+3x+2$ .
Instead of substituting $x=f(u)$ so $u=f^{-1}(x)$ ,can't we use the property:

$\int_a ^ bf(x)dx+\int_{f(b)}^{f(a)}f^{-1}(y)dy=bf(b)−af(a)$

Comment: This should help. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: \ followed by int f(x)dx for $\int f(x)dx$.

Comment: Even if you don’t know how to type an integral, putting the $ signs around your formulae is still pretty easy to do.

Comment: Instead of integrating the inverse of $f(x)$ between $x=-2$ and $x=6$, why don't you calculate the integral of $fx)$ between $y=-2$ and $y=6$? :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, we have

$\displaystyle \int_a ^ bf(x)dx+\int_{f(b)}^{f(a)}f^{-1}(y)dy=bf(b)−af(a)$

In this case $f(x) = x^3 + 3 x + 2$ , and we're given $f(a) = -2$, and $f(b) = 6$, so that $ a = -1 $ and $ b = 1$.  Hence,

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
\displaystyle \int_{-2}^{6} g(y) dy &= (1)(6) - (-1)(-2) - \int_{-1}^{1}( x^3 + 3 x + 2 ) dx = 4 - \left[ \dfrac{x^4}{4} + \dfrac{3 x^2}{2} + 2 x \right]_{-1}^{1} \\ &= 4 - 4 = 0 \end{split} \end{equation}$

Comment: No, but the answer is 9/2

Comment: No, I've plotted the function $f(x) = x^3 + 3 x + 2$, it is symmetrical about $(0, 2)$.  The points given are $(0, -2)$ and $(0, 6)$, which are also symmetrical about $(0,2)$, so the areas cancel out, and the net integral is zero.

Comment: Yea @ofcourse is right. If you plot the inverse function $x=y^3 + 3y + 2$ on desmos you can clearly see that the area enclosed by the graph and the x axis from $x=-2$ to $x=2$ equals the area enclosed by the graph and the x axis from $x=2$ to $x=6$